# Check position of two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check positioning of two elements?
For example:

```css
.bigBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed
  display: none;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

There is a big box over the whole website. And i have a button with positioning fixed and display none. The button should `fadeIn()` if it is 100px under the `.bigBox.`

Comment: @Alteyss - the question is tagged [jQuery]

Comment: Is a plain JS solution valid?

Answer (score 3):

First thing, the the position of `.bigBox`'s dimensions:

```
var bottomBigBox = $(".bigBox").offset().top + $(".bigBox").height();
var topOfBtn = $(".btn").offset().top;

// Check the condition and fade it.
if (bottomBigBox + 100 == topOfBtn)
  $(".btn").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position()` or `offset()` methods to know the position of the element relative to the parent or relative to the document respectively.

```
 $('.element').position().top; // returns the top value relative to parent
 $('.element').position().left; // returns the left value relative to parent

 $('.element').offset().top; // returns the top value relative to document
 $('.element').offset().left; // returns the left value relative to document
```

See more:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

https://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why not ? He asked for a way to solve its issue, it is.

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar ! I meet you some months ago and I think that you are a genius in this discipline, it's because I have a respect to you. Your answer is good and put a copy&paste solution to the OP. But OP asked: `Is there a way to check positioning of two elements?`, and my answer is for this. By this mode OP can think in how to use them to the purpose, so the learning is better that copy&paste. However, I vote up to your answer, because there are a real solution inside it. See you soon!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Awesome. Liked your response! `:)`. I just asked why. LoL. I have voted for you too bro! `:)`

Comment: The only problem with these people is, I agree with what you do. Fostering a better culture is one thing. But at the same time, just answering, like, "Okay, go check this website" is not a right thing, and *we don't learn anything* from that. I generally solve it for my satisfaction as well as making someone happy. Isn't that good and challenging? `:)` My approach might be wrong. But what do you think genuinely? Should I change myself?

Comment: psst: I hope I didn't offend you by asking that stupid question. Lemme remove it. LoL. I feel guilty now!

Comment: No, no way! Don't change yourself. Every person is perfect making as them makes comfortable. Many times I answer with a perfect copy&paste code, in the most cases the OP attach a fiddle and I modify that to works, but in this case I don't make it. However, now the OP have got a lot of information about his doubt.

Comment: You don't offend me, don't worry!

Answer (score 2):

You can get an element position with [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). Then you can sum its computed [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and the desired *margin* by `100`:

```
var bb = $(".bigBox");
var o = bb.offset();
var h = bb.height();

$(".btn").css("top", o.top + h + 100).fadeIn();
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v8602yhL/)

Why use `height()` ? It will get the element computed height, so if you change on CSS or even if you use an relative value, it will work.

**With plain Javascript**

```
var bb = document.querySelector(".bigBox");
var t = bb.offsetTop;
var h = bb.offsetHeight;

document.querySelector(".btn").style.top = t + h + 100 + "px";

$(".btn").fadeIn(); // jQuery only for fadeIn effect
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v8602yhL/2/)